# Eric Evans book - Cargo shipping example - Repository purpose

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm reading Evans's book Domain Driven Design, and I'm a bit stuck on understanding the example about Cargo Shipping and repositories, in chapter 7.

In "An Alternative Design of the Cargo AGGREGATE" he replaced Delivery History's collection with a query in order to reduce circular complexity and prevent transactions from locking.

Now I'm puzzled, wasn't the whole purpose of introducing Repositories separation of infrastructure layer from domain? If Deivery History is going to make queries, than it eather needs a reference to an appropriate repository or it itself has to implement some of the repository responsibilities? How does separation of entities and repositories work?

Answer (score 0):

[Implementing Domain Driven Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?page_id=168) By Vernon explores some of the practical considerations with this in more depth. In particular, in the [hexagonal architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture), you could actually treat the repository implementations as internal adapters. Then the repository is merely an interface to the underlying data store, and as such is fully part of the domain itself as an abstraction. This means any entity could reference the repository abstraction, and with the implementations outside the core domain, the layered architecture is preserved.

Of course there are many ways to implement this, and I think in some ways the original Evans book is not as prescriptive about the specifics, and rather focuses on the key patterns rather than all the implementation details.